# Display Long form text in Text Widget : Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, text-widget

I'm trying to create Legal pages in my app such as terms and conditions and privacy policy pages.

Does Flutter have a widget that is specifically design to take in long form text besides using the default Text widget? Or is there a hack to this? Perhaps reading from a text file or so?

I'm trying to avoid using multiple Text widgets in my dart file to display my long form legal pages.

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than multiple widgets you can wrap it

Comment: The default Text Widget should handle it without problems if it overflows you can use Expanded around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Expanded(            
    child: Text(
      'a long text',
      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
    ),
),
```

If you have various styling in the Text you can use `RichText`

```
RichText(
  overflow: TextOverflow.clip
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Super long bolded text here', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: 'Super long unbolded text here'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it helped me with my past knowledge from HTML CSS JS

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Privacy Policy",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 32,
                    )),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 24,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Get.back();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ), 
      
          Text(
          
         """
formation to us then you agree to provide true, 
current, complete and accurate information, and 
not to misrepresent your identity.  You also 
agree to keep Your Information current and to 
update Your Information if any of Your 
Information changes.
          """)
        ]),
      ),
    );
```